# Why char *s = "string" shows no error or warning when it is not const

Tags: c, pointers, constants

The following line

```
char *s = "string";
```

does not throw any warning/error on `gcc` even with `-Wall`.

AFAIK, the pointer `s` points directly to some portion of `.rodata`, making it a pointer to a `const` `char`.

So, why doesn't the pointer complain and expect:

```
const char *s = "string";
```

**Plus**: Anyway, Is(n't) it a better practice to use the latter?

Comment: @Dan , Read Only Data?

Comment: @CoolGuy I guess so, but I was surprised by the notation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From gcc compiling options :

> -Wwrite-strings
>   When compiling C, give string constants the type const char[length] so that copying the address of one into a non-const char * pointer produces a warning. These warnings help you find at compile time code that can try to write into a string constant, but only if you have been very careful about using const in declarations and prototypes. Otherwise, it is just a nuisance. This is why we did not make -Wall request these warnings.

So apparently you need to allow -Wwrite-strings explicitly, while Wall doesn't include it.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally any attempt to modify the contents of an string literal is an Undefined Behavior. Hence, it is always encouraged to use a `const` while declaring a string literal.

```
 const char *s = "string";
```

instead of,

```
 char *s = "string";
```

In fact, in `C++` it is deprecated to declare a string literal without the `const` though not in `C`. However, declaring a string literal with a `const` gives you the advantage that compilers would usually give you a warning in case you attempt to modify the string literal in second case.